# Android Studio: adding build.gradle.kts (Kotlin DSL script) while creating new module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin-dsl

Recently I've migrated all my build scripts to Kotlin DSL.

When I'm adding a new module in Android Studio I've got autogenerated build script written in Groovy.

How can I update Android Studio new module template to use autogenerated build script written in Kotlin DSL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be available in Android Studio Bumblebee.[image]

Follow the issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144835294